# How do I enable the official Java plugin in the latest version of Google Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, chromium

I was using Chromium, which runs smoothly, and was forced to upgrade to Chrome (mega.co.nz obliged me to). Now I can't execute applets in Chrome. Checking the installed plugins in both browsers, I see that Chromium has both icedtea7 and Java whereas Chrome has only icedtea7 plugin. So I have a potential culprit but don't know how to enable the Java plugin on Chrome. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please mention your Chrome + Java versions?

Comment: Sure, @RolandiXor: Chrome-> 26.0.1410.63 and Java -> "1.6.0_24" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk basically, you need to create a soft link to your JDK's `libnpjp2.so` in `~/.mozilla/plugins`.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, Terry. Thank you. Would you please rewrite it as response, so we can vote?